Relative Quaternion rotations in Blender Python
I'm trying to calculate the relative/local rotation between two Quaternions q1 and q2.  The Quaternion represent a rotation in world space.  I don't care about that I just want to know the how much q2 rotated as it relates to q1.
Here is an example of what I'm doing (in Python):
import mathutils
q1 = mathutils.Quaternion((0.9962, 0.0130, 0.0068, -0.0859))
q2 = mathutils.Quaternion((0.7521, 0.0097, -0.0060, 0.6590))
print((q2 @ q1.inverted()).to_euler('XYZ'))
<Euler (x=-0.0242, y=-0.0339, z=1.6112), order='XYZ'>

And that looks about right!  I did rotate the object ~90° about the Z axis.  Here is a visual representation (Green being the starting Rotation and Red being the ending):

But when I try the same thing with some different Quaternions (in this case the starting rotation is different):
q1 = mathutils.Quaternion((0.7108, -0.0966,  -0.6877, -0.1119))
q2 = mathutils.Quaternion((0.5965, -0.5453, -0.4230, 0.4097))
print((q2 @ q1.inverted()).to_euler('XYZ'))
<Euler (x=-1.5252, y=0.3413, z=-0.2604), order='XYZ'>

But this doesn't make sense!  I did the same thing.  Relative to q1 I rotated the object about q1 Z axis.  But the result shows that I rotated it on the X axis.  This seems to be factoring in the world space rotation.

I only care about the local rotation, which in both cases it has been rotated about the Z axis of q1.  So why is one my results returning a X rotation and the other a Z rotation?
